# How to fix "1054 - unknown column on clause"

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a sql code to get the data from my MySQL database. but when i run sql query it returns an error.

How an I fix this. Im new to this and I googled but i cant find a solution.

> 1054 - Unknown column 'departments.department_id' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT
    staff_data.first_name,
    staff_data.middle_name,
    staff_data.last_name,
    staff_data.gender,
    staff_data.civil_status,
    staff_data.birthday,
    staff_data.address_line_1,
    staff_data.address_line_2,
    staff_data.address_line_3,
    staff_data.contact_no_1,
    staff_data.contact_no_2,
    staff_data.nationality,
    staff_data.religion,
    staff_data.email,
    staff_data.is_deleted,
    staff_data.nic_number,
    staff_data.is_admin,
    departments.department_name,
    job_positions.position_name 
FROM
    departments,
    employee_position
    INNER JOIN job_positions ON job_positions.department_id = 
departments.department_id 
    AND departments.department_id = job_positions.department_id 
    AND employee_position.position_id = job_positions.position_id
    INNER JOIN staff_data ON employee_position.user_id = 
staff_data.nic_number 
WHERE
    employee_position.is_valid = 1
```

Comment: it is obvious but you don't have column  `department_id` in `departments` table

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed! (Explicit JOIN chains are evaluated before comma separated joins, so your ON clause hasn't got the departments columns in scope.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please *don't* mix old school join syntax with modern syntax (the latter which you should be using only).  Here is your corrected query using modern join syntax:

```
SELECT
    s.first_name,
    s.middle_name,
    s.last_name,
    s.gender,
    s.civil_status,
    s.birthday,
    s.address_line_1,
    s.address_line_2,
    s.address_line_3,
    s.contact_no_1,
    s.contact_no_2,
    s.nationality,
    s.religion,
    s.email,
    s.is_deleted,
    s.nic_number,
    s.is_admin,
    d.department_name,
    j.position_name 
FROM departments d
INNER JOIN job_positions j
    ON j.department_id = d.department_id 
INNER JOIN employee_position e
    ON e.position_id = j.position_id
INNER JOIN staff_data s
    ON e.user_id = s.nic_number
WHERE
    e.is_valid = 1;
```

The error you are seeing is probably coming from the fact that your use of old school join syntax put the MySQL parser into a certain mode, which is then not behaving as you expect subsequently.

Note that I also introduced table aliases, which makes the query easier to read.

Comment: *That* looks better!

Comment: It returns an error like this.  ' > 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near e.position_id = j.position_id INNER JOIN staff_data s ON e.user_id = s.nic at line 25' .My MariaDB Server Version is :10.1.34.

Comment: @Thilinajayakody Sorry, that line was missing `ON`.  I did not test my query, instead just basing it on your question.

Comment: It works. thank you. can you recommend a website to learn modern SQL syntax as tutorials.

Comment: I don't like most SQL tutorial sites.  Spending time on Stack Overflow is honestly a good way to learn.  Check out Tech on the Net for a good SQL reference site.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with first join

```
SELECT
    staff_data.first_name,
    staff_data.middle_name,
    staff_data.last_name,
    staff_data.gender,
    staff_data.civil_status,
    staff_data.birthday,
    staff_data.address_line_1,
    staff_data.address_line_2,
    staff_data.address_line_3,
    staff_data.contact_no_1,
    staff_data.contact_no_2,
    staff_data.nationality,
    staff_data.religion,
    staff_data.email,
    staff_data.is_deleted,
    staff_data.nic_number,
    staff_data.is_admin,
    departments.department_name,
    job_positions.position_name 
FROM
    departments,
    employee_position
    INNER JOIN job_positions ON 
    job_positions.department_id = <change to req col>
    -- departments.department_id join between employee_position and job_positions, but join is on department table 
    AND departments.department_id = job_positions.department_id 
    AND employee_position.position_id = job_positions.position_id
    INNER JOIN staff_data ON employee_position.user_id = 
staff_data.nic_number 
WHERE
    employee_position.is_valid = 1
```